# Comparison method violates its general contract in sorting method

Tags: java, android, sorting

I get an error in my sorting method.

> Comparison method violates its general contract

This is my sorting object with sort method

```
public abstract class ComparablePerson extends IDValueItem implements
        Comparable<ComparablePerson> {

    private int score;
    private String itemID,itemName;

    //setters and getters

    public int compareTo(ComparablePerson another) {
    if (score == another.getScore())
        return this.getItemName().compareToIgnoreCase(another.getItemName());
    else if ((score) > another.getScore())
        return 1;
    else
        return -1;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    final ComparablePerson other = (ComparablePerson) o; 

    if (score == other.getScore() && this.getItemName().equalsIgnoreCase(other.getItemName())) 
        return true; 
    else 
        return false; 
}
```

I just call 
                Collections.sort(ComparablePersonCollection);

What can be the cause of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `compareTo` and `equals` method implementations seem to be inconsistent, the error is telling you that for the same two objects `equals` gives true while `compareTo` does not produce zero, which is incorrect. I suggest you invoke `compareTo` from `equals` to ensure consistency or otherwise define a custom `Comparator<T>`.

Simply do:

```
public abstract class ComparablePerson extends IDValueItem implements Comparable<ComparablePerson> {

    private int score;
    private String itemID,itemName;

    //setters and getters

    public int compareTo(ComparablePerson another) {
    if (score == another.getScore())
        return this.getItemName().compareToIgnoreCase(another.getItemName());
    else if ((score) > another.getScore())
        return 1;
    else
        return -1;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        return compareTo(o) == 0; 
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

ComparablePerson is abstract, the comparison method is probably overloaded elsewhere...

Can you post the client (which owns the collection) and the concrete classes?

This code works well:

```
public class ComparablePerson implements Comparable< ComparablePerson > {
   public ComparablePerson( int score, String name ) {
      _score    = score;
      _itemName = name;
   }

   @Override public int compareTo( ComparablePerson another ) {
      int delta = _score - another._score;
      if( delta != 0 ) return delta;
      return _itemName.compareToIgnoreCase( another._itemName );
   }

   @Override public boolean equals( Object o ) {
      return 0 == compareTo((ComparablePerson)o);
   }

   @Override public int hashCode() {
      return super.hashCode();
   }

   private final int    _score;
   private final String _itemName;

   public static void main( String[] args ) {
      List< ComparablePerson > oSet = new LinkedList<>();
      oSet.add( new ComparablePerson( 5, "x" ));
      oSet.add( new ComparablePerson( 5, "y" ));
      oSet.add( new ComparablePerson( 5, "z" ));
      oSet.add( new ComparablePerson( 6, "x" ));
      oSet.add( new ComparablePerson( 6, "y" ));
      oSet.add( new ComparablePerson( 6, "z" ));
      Collections.sort( oSet );
      System.err.println( "Ok" );
   }
}
```